# How can I get the session IP address from Openfire with smack?

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, smack

I'm developing an application that in a moment need must run via p2p. I need the IP address of  some users of a group. How can I get the session IP address from Openfire server with Asmack?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the openfire admin interface, head over to Sessions -> Active Sessions -> Client Sessions. Here you will see a list of all the users currently logged on to the system, with their IP and client information.